# Google Charts Format Date as mm:ss.00

Tags: javascript, date, google-visualization

I am trying to display a graph of competitive swimming times using Google charts. Swimming uses times down to the hundredths of a second.  After some work, I managed to get the times to graph using the Date object

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Number', 'Time'],
  ['1',  new Date(2014,5,5,0,1,47,470)],
  ['2',  new Date(2014,5,5,0,1,45,880)],
  ['3',   new Date(2014,5,5,0,1,43,520)],
  ['4',   new Date(2014,5,5,0,1,40,670)]
]);
```

The table above represents times between 1:47.47 and 1:40.67.  Next, I applied a DateFormat to the data table which has removed the date portion of the data, but I am having trouble representing the hundredths of a second portion of the time.  I've tried

```
var timeFormatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({ pattern: "m:ss.00" });
```

and

```
var timeFormatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({ pattern: "m:ss.##" });
```

But this just results in the times on the graph displaying with either `00` or `##` in the place where I would expect the hundreths to appear.  The graph itself is placing the points as though it recognizes the milliseconds portion of the date object.

Is there a way to have the hundreths of a second appear when I hover the mouse over the data point.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robbertv/B5B9F/) of what I'm working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this pattern:

```
pattern: "m:ss.SSS"
```

Now, when you hover over your data points, the correct numbers should appear.  See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B5B9F/9/)

Comment: Thank you. That did it.  I just didn't know the letters that represented the fractional part of the seconds.

Comment: No problem.  Check out the documentation.  If you scroll down, you'll see a list of all the available patterns: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dateformatter

Comment: Awesome. I had looked at that page, just didn't go far enough. My bad for not reading the whole thing :)